# [Renderbuffer]Which one is telling me the truth?

Tags: opengl

So I was doing my part in implementing an OpenCV program combined with OpenGL and the thing is that I don't know which one is telling me the truth.

[Wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format)

[API](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRenderbufferStorage.xml)

The former one tells me that I can use GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8 on setting an image format in this function

```
void glRenderbufferStorage( GLenum target,  
  GLenum internalformat,  
  GLsizei width,  
  GLsizei height);
```

whereas the latter one explains that I cannot use GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8 but rather
*GL_RGBA4, GL_RGB565, GL_RGB5_A1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, or GL_STENCIL_INDEX8.*

Which one is showing me the right way to implement the function?

Comment: Don't post pictures of webpages. Post an actual link.

Comment: Didn't know that, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both right.

The OpenGL Wiki is for *OpenGL*, not OpenGL *ES 2.0*. Whereas OpenGL ES 2.0's documentation is for OpenGL ES 2.0, not desktop OpenGL.

The various documentation is correct for the API that they document.

Comment: I didn't see the difference among those two pages. So the first one is describing about OpenGL ES and the latter one is showing me some info about native OpenGL. Right?

Comment: Thanks for the answer